# When to use "be worth VERBing" and when to use "be worthy VERBing"?

Tags: word-usage, expression-choice

Consider this sentence:

1. This movie is worth watching.
2. This movie is worth**y** watching.

I am confused about these two words *worth* and *worthy*. When should you use “be worth VERBing” and when should you instead use “be worthy VERBing”?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600416/2085).

Answer (score 3):

*worthy V-ing* is not acceptable at all, so I assume you really meant to ask about *worthy **of** V-ing*.

*worthy of* is usually used with a noun, rather than a verb, as in

> The esteemed professor is worthy of respect.

This [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=worth%20watching%2Cworthy%20of%20watching&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworth%20watching%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cworthy%20of%20watching%3B%2Cc0) shows that *worthy of watching* is used a miniscule amount compared to *worth watching*.

*worth V-ing* is the normal way to express this, as per this [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/worth):

> 2.1 Used to suggest that the specified course of action may be advisable:
>   *the company’s service schemes are worth checking out*

Comment: What about "to be worth V-ing"? what does it mean?

Comment: I've added the definition of _worth_ that explains what it means

Comment: Are you sure worthy plus ving is not acceptable?